# Solr exact phrase match not working

Tags: solr, solr4

I am trying to setup exact phrase-match in [Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/), 
it should match "this is a ball" exactly the documents containing this phrase, including the stopwords. I configured schema.xml as follows, it's not working. Please let me know what I have missed out. I am newbie to Solr

```xml
<fieldType name="c_text" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>

    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't apply any tokenizer to that field and make it as a **String field**. String field matches exact patterns including stopwords. This will work for you

Comment: If I  remove the **tokenizer** tag, it shows folowing error.
**analyzer without class or tokenizer**
And if I made it String field, it does not match the doc. containing "**this is a ball**. It is red in color"

Comment: "this is a ball" is it a complete string or a substring of your field?If you want to match complete field then it will work with String field. But if it is a substring then that won't be possible unless you specify some particular stopword like "Do you think; this is a ball;" and specify ; as a stop word then you can search it that way.

Comment: Yes, it's a substring. You mean to say, substring match is not possible in Solr?.

Comment: Solr is an indexer server. So what you give to solr, you can retrieve it. You have to find a way to index these substrings which seems highly improbable.Or i can say that exact substring match for substrings is not possible.What you can do is create a multivalue  field and keep all your substrings as a list of values..